# How can i use if condition in vars file in ansible

Tags: variables, ansible

Is it possible to do something like this in anisble vars file

```
env: "{{ lookup('env','MY_ENV') }}"    
user: tom if {{ env }} else mike
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer to your question, I think you cannot use `env` as variable because it's reserved word in ansible:

```
---
- hosts: all 
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ENV: "dev"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{%- if ENV == 'dev' -%} tom {%- else -%} mike {%- endif -%}"
```

Result when the value of `ENV` is `dev`:

```
% ansible-playbook -i "localhost," test.yml -c local

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "tom"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Result when the value of `ENV` is something else:

```
% ansible-playbook -i "localhost," test.yml -c local

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "mike"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Hope that help you

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use another lookup into a json file containing the user-env mappings. E.g.:

user_envs.json:

```
{
    "dev": "tom",
    "prod": "mike"
}
```

lookup:

```
{{ (lookup('file', 'user_envs.json') | from_json).get('dev') }}
```

Don't have an env to try it now but give it a shot!